# 403 forbidden inside the project directory

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to host a demo website which is written using Zend framework on mac OS X Mountain Lion. I got 403 forbidden when i tried accessing the directory structure in my browser(The demo directory contains application, library and public directories), by pointing my browser to demo.local. I followed the instructions as on http://support.apple.com/kb/ta25038 and then restarted apache, and then tried again, but now, I see application and library directories, but not public. When I try demo.local/public, I get a 403 forbidden error. How should I solve this?

Comment: when hosting the application of the zend framework, you should make the `public` folder of zend the DocumentRoot of the virtual host. You shouldn't access this folder via url. Anyway, it will be also helpful to see the error(s) which occur on accessing the project. The error(s)will be saved in /var/log/apache2/error_log

Comment: I tried changing the document root to the public folder...but it doesn't help

Comment: so what do you see in /var/log/apache2/error_log? Can you copy it here?